# sparql query returning nothing

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

Why this SPARQL not returning any value

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?Abstract 
WHERE
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cologne>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?page .
?page   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>  ?Abstract.

FILTER (lang(?Abstract)='en')
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons. Firstly, there are no redirects of `Cologne`, but there are redirects to it. So:

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT * 
WHERE
{
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cologne> 
        <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?page .
}
```

returns nothing, whereas:

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT * 
WHERE
{
    ?page 
        <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects>
            <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cologne> .
}
```

does work.

Secondly none of these redirects appears to have an abstract. `Cologne` itself does, so you could just use that:

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?Abstract 
WHERE
{
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cologne>
        <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>  ?Abstract.

    FILTER (lang(?Abstract)='en')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not return any value because nothing matches your query. If you dereference the URI for Cologne, you can see that there is no `wikiPageRedirects` property. `dbpedia:Cologne` does not redirects to anything, but many resources redirect to `dbpedia:Cologne`. However, the resources that redirect to Cologne do not have an abstract. In fact, this is quite normal: in Wikipedia, you cannot edit a page that redirects to another one, as you are necessarily redirected to the other. So when dbpedia extracts data from Wikipedia, of course there is nothing about the redirected pages.